# Can't seem to calculate the Laplacian matrix in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have been tirelessly trying to find the Laplacian matrix but I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
df = loadmat('/xxx/xxxx/pubmedanatomy.mat')['X']

# degree matrix
D = np.diag(np.sum(np.array(df.todense()), axis=1))
print('degree matrix:')
print(D)

# laplacian matrix
L = D - df
print('laplacian matrix:')
print(L)
```

where matrix called `df` is of type :

```
<3291x13692 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 279414 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

output and the error:

```
degree matrix:
[[88.000 0.000 0.000 ... 0.000 0.000 0.000]
 [0.000 59.000 0.000 ... 0.000 0.000 0.000]
 [0.000 0.000 47.000 ... 0.000 0.000 0.000]
 ...
 [0.000 0.000 0.000 ... 108.000 0.000 0.000]
 [0.000 0.000 0.000 ... 0.000 207.000 0.000]
 [0.000 0.000 0.000 ... 0.000 0.000 89.000]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-e404e383ee84> in <module>
      4 print(D)
      5 # laplacian matrix
----> 6 L = D - df
      7 print('laplacian matrix:')
      8 print(L)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __rsub__(self, other)
    446                                       'nonzero scalar is not supported')
    447         elif isdense(other):
--> 448             other = np.broadcast_to(other, self.shape)
    449             return self._rsub_dense(other)
    450         else:

<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_to(*args, **kwargs)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py in broadcast_to(array, shape, subok)
    178            [1, 2, 3]])
    179     """
--> 180     return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)
    181 
    182 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok, readonly)
    123     it = np.nditer(
    124         (array,), flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok', 'zerosize_ok'] + extras,
--> 125         op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')
    126     with it:
    127         # never really has writebackifcopy semantics

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3291,3291) and requested shape (3291,13692)
```

Degree matrix is being calculated but the Laplacian matrix is giving me `ValueError`. What is the problem here?

Comment: Looks like `D` is a square dense array, (3291,3291), and `df` is csr sparse with shape (3291,13692).  Even if  you used `df.todense()` as you did earlier, you can't subtract these two shapes.  I would think that would be obvious.  Elementwsie subtraction requires matching arrays!

Comment: @hpaulj How can I fix this? Really need the help like right now :/

Comment: Check out [scipy.sparse.csgraph.laplacian](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.laplacian.html)

Comment: Is it possible to calculate a Laplacian for a matrix that isn't square?  Does the `df` shape make sense to you?

Comment: "How can I fix this": make sure `D` and `df` have shapes that play nicely with each other. That's a matrix math requirement that no library or code is going to fix. How can you do that? We can't tell you unless you give more details on where those matrices come from

Comment: @itprorh66 I think that doesn't apply to my problem of matrices being unequal or does it? Can you suggest something with my current code?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi @hpaulj `df` consists of Bag of Words. Can I calculate the Laplacian matrix out of it? If yes, how can I make it to work?

Comment: The csgraph function requires a square matrix.  So does your calculation.  Your `df` is not square. We can't help you.

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/4685471) (tl;dr: **never** - edited out).